# Understanding a Perl one-line command in a script

Tags: bash, perl

I'm trying to understand how to use this Perl command in a bash script:

```
perl -nle 'print ++$_'
```

Comment: which part(s) are you having trouble understanding? perl? -n? -l? -e? print? ++? $_?

Comment: -nle and 'print ++$_'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It reads lines from standard input or file, assumes that every line is a number and prints number incremented by one,

```
seq 5 | perl -nle 'print ++$_'
2
3
4
5
6
```

How command line switches are transformed into full script,

```
perl -MO=Deparse -nle 'print ++$_'
BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    chomp $_;
    print ++$_;
}
```

- `n` adds `while(<>){}` loop around code
- `l` chomps every line, and `$\ = "\n"` (newline after every print)
- `e` always before quoted perl code

Comment: Not necessarily a number.  Perl is ok with incrementing letters as well.

Comment: @Mr.Llama yes, letters too.

Answer (score 3):

Flags passed to perl are explained on the page in [`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/perlrun.html)

- **`-n`** causes the whole Perl "program" to be run once on each line of the input, with `$_` taking the value of each input line in turn,
- **`-l`** does "magic" to make linefeeds "work",
- **`-e`** provides the Perl program in question on the command line itself.

The program is therefore `print ++$_` which is run for each line, and prints the value generated when you attempt to add 1 to the line content. For lines which look like numbers, this will simply print a number one greater. For lines which are simply ASCII letters, autoincrement magic will happen (`aa` will become `ab` and so on). For lines which are *not* numbers, it will take their value as `0` and print `1`.